# JobIntentService? or IntentService with ForegroudService? or both? for Locationtracker + Timer

Tags: kotlin, intentservice, background-service, foreground-service, jobintentservice

- What i want: Building an app which tracks the location and the time in background for backpacking. The app should track the location and the time in background.
- Question: which one should I use: JobIntentService? or IntentService with ForegroudService? or both?
- My resume: (after reading a lot of explanations)
  JobIntentservice: will approximately STOP after 10 minutes(because of the JobScheduler)!
  IntentService: will STOP, if the app is killed!

Am I wrong?
I would appreciate some help!
Thank you

Comment: you should create a service and make it foreground service  with notification.

Comment: Thank you. i will tell the results

Comment: the foregroundservice with  a notification works perfect, THANK YOU